# GoLang. Вывод аргументов командной строки

Tags: golang, командная-строка

Коллеги, добрый вечер.

Стал изучать Go. Пытаюсь понять, что делает код ниже. В учебнике написано, что он выводи аргументы командной строки.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"os"
)

func main() {
  var s, sep string
  for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
     s += sep + os.Args[i]
     sep = " "
 }
fmt.Println(s)
}
```

При запуске ничего не происходит, и только один раз, когда я удалил пакет strings из кода, вышло "# command-line-arguments"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так? Может ли быть, что Win10 не подходит, и его надо выполнять на UNIX системе?

Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Голова прояснилась. Для того, чтобы программа вывела аргументы командной строки, их надо ввести. Это очевидно.

Пишем, например: "go run echo.go a b c d f" в консоль.

И получим наши "a b c d f"